# Getting Error 403 Trying to update PAT on Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Based on the doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/pats/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) provided by MS, i'm trying to update my Token expiration date through the api. I made a sample request using a full access token to authenticate and passing the authorizationId of the token i want to update in the body:

[My sample request using Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLSkm.png)

And it keeps returning Error 403, I've checked my organization policies and tried by adding or removing parameters from body but it din't work.
I've also made another request to get the list of tokens on my organization with the same token authorization and api version and that went well.

Comment: Though it says, "Use any value for the user name..." have you tried adding something in the Username field and not leaving it blank?

Comment: @joelforsyth thanks for your answer. Yeah, i tried with a dummy username too

Comment: Since the error is a 403 (and not a 401) that generally means you have correct authentication, just not _authorization_. Since you were able to perform GETs with no issue, my next guess is a permissions or access issue. The policies may be correct, but it could be touching other Azure resources that aren't apparent on the surface. Hard to diagnose beyond that though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your screenshot you are using the `Basic Auth` with PAT.

Please note that you must authenticate with an [Azure AD token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens) to use this API instead of a PAT token. In order to call the API directly, you need to provide an Azure AD access token as a `Bearer` token in `Authorization header` of your request.  Please see [Manage personal access tokens (PATs) using REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/manage-personal-access-tokens-via-api?view=azure-devops) and [Q: Can I use basic auth with all Azure DevOps REST APIs?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows#q-can-i-use-basic-auth-with-all-azure-devops-rest-apis) for details.

You can follow below steps to get the AAD Bearer token:

1. Install the [Azure Az PowerShell module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-6.6.0).
2. Login with a user account which has the permission in your DevOps org (Owner or PCA) with command `Connect-AzAccount`

- 1.) Alternately login from the cloud shell with command `Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication`, you will see the following message:

  [image]
- 2.) Then copy the url `https://microsoft.com/devicelogin` and open in a new tap, enter the code `IVR7VRWJQ` to authenticate.
- 3.) Login with the Azure DevOps organization owner or other PCA account. After successful login you will see the account info, then follow below steps to get the Bearer Token.

3. Get the Bearer token:

   `$token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798").Token`

   `$token`
   [image]
4. Copy and use the token in script or Postman to update the PAT.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer Andy! I was able to get the bearer token this way and copy it to postman but i'm getting 203 Non Authorative Information. Based on the doc you provided i tried to setup the Oauth2 authorization to the api adding postman to my Azure AD apps but same result

Comment: I followed the guide on this link https://dev.to/425show/calling-an-azure-ad-secured-api-with-postman-22co to make a request to the api. Still 403 Non Authorative Information

Comment: @Rodri Please make sure you have set the scope to `"499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"` when trying to generate the token.

Comment: but Get-AzAccessToken doesn't allow specifying scopes right?

Comment: @Rodri If the logged in user has the correct permission to access the Azure DevOps organization, by default it's set the scope `"499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"`. That's the easiest way to get the AAD bearer token. For example, `Connect-AzAccount` with the owner account. If you register application separately, then please make sure you have set the scope to "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"

Comment: @Rodri I have updated the answer, the easiest way is to follow exactly the steps I mentioned in my answer. Please login with your Azure DevOps owner or PCA account.

Comment: Thanks for your answers @Andy Li-MSFT, unfortunately it's still not working for me, even by using an owner account but maybe it can help others. Since it works perfectly in your example, i will check my organization settings again, perhaps something is missing

Comment: Update. I've been able to consume the api using other organization so i can confirn this work